# I need to map keys to csv values that I read from an URL using Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, dictionary

I need to map keys to csv values that I read from an URL using Python 2.7.
The target computer that will run this Python script is a RaspberryPi 3 running Raspbian 9 (Raspberry Pi distribution that is based on Debian 9).

I need to read a continously changing set of values from a Solar Inverter (a SAJ Sununo 3K-M solar inverter to be precise) and map it to fixed set of fieldnames.

The order of the expected values is exactly like the order of the fieldnames, but they need to be mapped to each other. The URL is also what it needs to be be

I have tried to read the values and I can succesfully read the values, but I can't actually map the values to variables to do something useful.

An example of the response that I get if I read the csv values is below:

```
['1', '4378', '998', '668', '69', '1842', '328', '1226', '336', '65535', '65535', '65535', '65535', '65535', '65535', '65535', '65535', '65535', '65535', '65535', '65535', '65535', '65535', '992', '4999', '2364', '421', '65535', '65535', '65535', '65535', '3663', '348', '343', '2']
```

I would very much appreciate it if someone could have a crack at what I'm trying to achieve.

I have copy/pasted the code that I have written sofar below.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# This script reads the output of SAJ Solar Inverters and parses it so that it can be used in a meaningful way 
# Import libraries
import csv
import urllib2
import base64

def main():
    global username,password, responselist
username = 'USER-LOGIN'
password = 'USER-PASSWORD'
statusfieldnames = ['Statistics', 'Total_Generated', 'Total_Running Time', 'Today_Generated', 'Today_Running_Time', 'PV1_Voltage', 'PV1_Current', 'PV2_Voltage', 'PV2_Current', 'PV3_Voltage', 'PV3_Current', 'PV1_StrCurr1', 'PV1_StrCurr2', 'PV1_StrCurr3', 'PV1_StrCurr4', 'PV2_StrCurr1', 'PV2_StrCurr2', 'PV2_StrCurr3', 'PV2_StrCurr4', 'PV3_StrCurr1', 'PV3_StrCurr2', 'PV3_StrCurr3', 'PV3_StrCurr4', 'Grid-connected_Power', 'Grid-connected_Frequency', 'Line1_Voltage', 'Line1_Current', 'Line2_Voltage', 'Line2_Current', 'Line3_Voltage', 'Line3_Current', 'Bus_Voltage', 'Device_Temperature', 'CO2emission_Reduction', 'Other_Status']

request = urllib2.Request("http://IP-ADDRESS-OF-RPI3/status/status.php")
base64string = base64.b64encode('%s:%s' % (username, password))
request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)   
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
status = csv.reader(response, delimiter=",")
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing the ordering and lengths are exactly the same you could use this code:

```
valDict={}
for f, v in zip(statusfieldnames, response):
    valDict[f] = v
```